# Can't get datepicker plugin to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Can't get this plugin to work in my browser, so I'm trying to figure out where I'm going wrong. I can't even get it to go in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pkDLJ/2/

I have to use the 1.7.2 library according to my developer. I think I linked the JS file up through External Resources. Here it is, if not:

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple. I don't normally work with jquery so please forgive me. The head in my HTML includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.datepick.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    $('#popupDatepicker').datepick();
});
</script>
```

I have no errors in the Console. The stylesheet is loading. Thanks for any help. Pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Zj8kB/

Haven't looked at the documentation thoroughly but removing the `hasDatepick` class fixed the issue.

Edit: Here is one line I can find in the documentation at the bottom of the "Introduction" `Processed fields are marked with a class of hasDatepick and are not re-processed if targetted a second time`.

Please change your html markup as follows(All I did was removed the `hasDatepick` class from your original markup you had at the fiddle):

```
<div class="fltlft">
    <input type="text" id="popupDatepicker" class="formBox" name="DOB" type="text" placeholder="DOB" />
</div>
```

Comment: That was the problem!! I never would have guessed that class was an issue, since I'm following the site's example. Thanks!

Comment: @user2574250, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the way this plugin works is in such a way that other classes interfere with it's functiontality, I forked your example and removed the classes on the input just to find out that it worked, make sure you are not overriding any CSS class or if it works for you avoid adding more clases (or add them with JS after loading).

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="fltlft">
    <input id="popupDatepicker" name="DOB" type="text" placeholder="DOB" />
</div>
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/uAu3b/)